# Calling a certain column from a data frame inside an R function

Tags: r

I was just trying to call a certain column inside an R function using the code below but it only returns a null value. I know it sounds stupid to call the column using the `$` sign. I know it can be done by defining the targeted column directly in the input of the function. However, I just want to know why the code below is not working. Thanks in advance!

```
fn <- function(data, var){
  return(data$var)
}
data(cars)
fn(cars, speed)
```

Comment: The various alternatives as well as the answer to "why doesn't `$` work" are included in various answers there, though you may need to read more than one answer.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't using the right keywords to search for a solution. I should've dug deeper before posting my question.